# Cocoa Lumberjack how to write in same folder with different file name

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, logging, cocoalumberjack

With help of this [CocoaLumberjack FileLogger logging to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921740/cocoalumberjack-filelogger-logging-to-multiple-files) , I am able to create multiple log files (with same name in multiple directories),

But I need to use `DDLog` in one of my project where it is required to write multiple logs files in the same directory with different names.

Is there any way to attain this?

Answer (score 0):

`DDFileLogger` uses `logFileManager` for managing logfiles. By default it uses `DDLogFileManagerDefault`. You can create your own file manager that confirms to `DDLogFileManager` protocol and provide whatever behavior you need.

The easiest way doing this is to copy `DDLogFileManagerDefault` and change it to feet your needs.